# I am trying to identify this plant

Tags: species-identification

I am trying to identify this medium arching shrub growing to about 1.5m high x 2m wide in the subtropical climate of the Mt Coot-tha Botanic Gardens in Brisbane, Australia. Unfortunately there was no label with it. The inflorescence is about 3cm across, a greenish yellow, and made up of many tentacle-like florets.  I don't think it is an Australian native plant.

[image: Inflorescence]

Comment: Best I could find is *Maclura pomifera*, but no pictures of this exact stage of development

Comment: Opposite, pubescent leaves with acuminate tip and truncate base. White stipule in background. Inflorescence appears to  be a compound cyme? Not sure if those are strange pubescent petals 
(unlikely?) or sepals or bracts in 7s. Initially made me think of *Hamamelis* flowers, but the yellow "tentacles" are not ribbon-like enough to be any *Hamamelis* I know or could find. Hmmmm

Comment: @theforestecologist could it be Listea glutinosa? It is native to Australia.

Comment: @trinitrotoluene doesn't look the same to me. E.g., leaf base and flowers look different. http://www.geocities.ws/wessaaliens/species/laurel.htm

Comment: @theforestecologist yeah you're right. I hadn't properly seen the leaf bases. Maybe op could post some more pictures from different angles.

Comment: See if you can find any pieces of fruit under the tree. some photos of the bark and the tree/shrub total shape would be help too.

Answer (score -1):

Finally, I found the info about this plant:

**Common name:** Buttontree

**Botanical name:** Terminalia pendula

**Family:** Combretaceae (Rangoon creeper family)

**Flowering:** June - September

Buttontree is a moderate sized tree with small leaves, which fall early in the dry season. Before falling the foliage of these trees turns a beautiful yellowish red. The leafy branches are pendulous and hang down gracefully. Leaves upto 3 cm appear in nearly opposite pairs. Tiny yellowish green flowers occur in spherical heads about 1 cm wide. Protruding stamens are prominently visible like a fuzz on the round heads. Fruits are sort of circular, clustered in round heads.

Source: [Terminalia pendula - Buttontree](http://www.flowersofindia.net/catalog/slides/Buttontree.html)

Comment: This appears to be incorrect. You could try to update with explicit evidence, but I'm not convinced your species is correct

Comment: You can try google searching the species, you will get the same result. Also, I reconfirmed my answer with my Botany Professors and its correct.

Comment: I agree that _Terminalia_ is incorrect. At a minimum, _Terminalia_ lacks the long sepals(?) of this plant. _Terminalia_ flowers also have a long style, while this plant has essentially no style.

Comment: It's hard to find a match. Based on the shape, margin and venation of the leaves it could really be _Terminalia_ but I think we need more information.